# FancyCoverFlow, view.getTag() returns null when I override onItemSelected() function

Tags: android, android-studio

I use `FancyCoverFlow` in my project.
In the this method

```
FancyCoverFlowAdapter.getCoverFlowItem(int position, View reusableView, ViewGroup parent)
```

I invoke `view.setTag(viewHolder)`. And in this adapter, `view.getTag()` can returns the `viewHolder` correctly.

But when I use `coverFlow.setOnItemSelectedListener(this)`, and override the below method, the `view.getTag()` returns `null`.

```
onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
```

so this is why? and how can I resolve this problem.